# echo a multidimensional array into multiple html table rows

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I have a query that I'm running and it will output an unknown number of results.  I want to display these results in a table of 5 columns.  So I need the array print until the sixth result and then start a new row.

The way I tried to do it was to take the original array and chunk it into blocks of 5.

```
$display=array_chunk($row_Classrooms,5);
```

which gives me an array like this.

```
  Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                  [id_room] => 1 
                  [Name] => Classroom 1 
                  [class] => Yes 
                  ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                  [id_room] => 5 
                  [Name] => Classroom 2 
                  [class] => Yes 
                  ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                  [id_room] => 6 
                  [Name] => Classroom 3 
                  [class] => Yes 
                  ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                  [id_room] => 7 
                  [Name] => Classroom 4 
                  [class] => Yes  
                  ) 
            [4] => Array ( 
                 [id_room] => 8 
                 [Name] => Classroom 5 
                 [class] => Yes 
                 ) 
            ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
           [0] => Array ( 
                  [id_room] => 9 
                  [Name] => Classroom 6 
                  [class] => Yes 
                  ) 
             ) 
   )
```

I'm then trying to echo this out with a pair of while loops, like such.

```
while ($rows = $display) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    while ($class = $rows) {
                        echo'<td>'.$class['name'].'<br>
                            <input name="check'.$i.' type="checkbox" value="'.$class['id_room'].'></td>';
                            $i++;
                    }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
```

When I run this it apparently gets stuck in a never ending loop because nothing gets displayed but the browser just keeps chewing up more and more memory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the while loops with foreach loops instead which solved the issue.

```
    foreach ($display as $rows) {
            echo '<tr class="popup">';
                foreach($rows as $class) {
                    if(isset($row_Rego)){
                        $exist=NULL;
                        $exist=array_search($class['id_room'], array_column($row_Rego, 'id_room'));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` statements are wrong. Have a look at [here](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.while.php) - in your `while`-statement you are always assigning the complete `$display` - not one entry.

You could try using `while(($rows = array_shift($display)) !== false)` - that will always get the first array item until there are no more items.

The same case in the second while-statement.

Comment: ok I tried your suggestion but it gave exactly the same result.  with your comment about the while loop can you explain what is different between my while loops and `while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($requeteID))`